# Use of the term first order dependency

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, terminology, variational-principle, action

In a question I am doing it says:

> *Show explicitly that the function $$y(t)=\frac{-gt^2}{2}+\epsilon t(t-1)$$ yields an action that has no first order dependency on $\epsilon$.*

Also my textbook says that

> *[...] if a certain function $x_0(t)$ yields a stationary value of $S$ then any other function very close to $x_0(t)$ (with the same endpoint values) yields essentially the same $S$, up to first order of any deviations.*

I am confused about the first order bit? In the first case does it mean that $\frac{\partial S}{\partial \epsilon}=0$ or that it does not depend of $\epsilon$ but may take some other constant value. In the second case does it mean likewise or something different, please explain?

Comment: What do you mean by a *function* yielding an *action*? Do we set $S = \int y(t) \mathrm{d}t$ or something?

Comment: @ACuriousMind No sorry, I think it means $S=\int L(y(t),y'(t),t) dt $ where L is the Lagrangian

Comment: @Danu I am not asking for a solution and can find it fine by myself I am simply wanting to know what it means when it says first order of any deviation and no first order dependency.

Comment: Okay. That simply means $\delta S =\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)$ where $\epsilon$ is small.

Comment: @Danu sorry, what is the relationship between $\delta S$ and $\frac{\partial S}{\partial \epsilon}$ if there is one?? thanks

Comment: $S$ is a functional, so it takes functions as arguments. This also means you take *functional* derivatives. So, something like $\frac{\delta S}{\delta y}$ would make more sense... In fact, what one usually does is set $\frac{\delta S}{\delta y}=0$, i.e. find a stationary point of the action, in order to derive the equations of motion.

Comment: @Danu are we simply defining $\delta S$ as the difference in the action from the stationary point and that of the new function?

Comment: No, but $\delta S$ is equal to zero when we are at a stationary point of the action, i.e. when an infinitesimal variation (usually of $y(t)$ leaves $S$ invariant (to first order).

Comment: @Danu What is $\delta S$ then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17132/discussion-between-danu-and-joseph).

Comment: this question's title should be made more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

1. The action is 
   $$\tag{A} S[y]:=\int_0^1 \! dt ~L(y,\dot{y}), \qquad L(y,\dot{y})~:=~\frac{m}{2}\dot{y}^2 -mgy,  $$
   with Dirichlet boundary conditions 
   $$\tag{B}  y(0)~=~0 \quad\text{and}\quad y(1)~=~-\frac{g}{2}. $$
2. Calculate explicitly the composed function
   $$\tag{C} s(\epsilon)~:=~ S[y_{\epsilon}] , $$
   where 
   $$\tag{D} y_{\epsilon}(t)~:=~-\frac{gt^2}{2}+\epsilon t(t-1).$$
3. Check that the virtual paths (D) satisfy the Dirichlet boundary conditions (B). Why do we need to check that?
4. Show explicitly that the function $s(\epsilon)$ has no first order dependence on $\epsilon$. What is the physical significance of this fact?

References:

1. [David Morin](http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~djmorin/book.html), *The Lagrangian Method,*  Chap 6, Lecture notes, 2007; Exercise 6.30.

Comment: This is the right question, It is your 4th hint that my question is manly about, I got $S=\frac{gm}{6}(g+1)+\frac{\epsilon^2}{6}$ as my answer, is  it enough to say that this does not depend on $\epsilon$ of power 1??

Comment: @Joseph: There is something wrong with the $m$ and $g$ dependences. Please double check your result.

Comment: Sorry this is what I got, $S=\frac{mg^2}{3}+\frac{ m\epsilon^2}{6}$

Answer (score 0):

First-Order Dependency – A dependency that represents a direct causal relationship (e.g. if agent x produces event z, we say that "x is a first-order dependency of z").

Reference:
http://www.testability.com/Reference/Glossaries.aspx?Glossary=DependencyModeling