# A question on elementary Lagrangian mechanics(perhaps a bit of maths)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle

I am stuck with this question

> Consider the action, from $t=0$ to $t=1$, of a ball dropped from rest. From the Euler-Lagrange equation, we know that $y(t)={-gt^2 \over 2}$ yields a stationary value of the action. Show explicitly that the particular function $y(t)={-gt^2 \over 2} + \epsilon t(t-1)$ yields an action that has no first-order dependence on $\epsilon$.

I tried first to write down the Lagrangian $$L=T-V = {m\dot y^2 \over 2}-mgy$$ then calculate the action as $$S=\int_0 ^1 L dt$$ and differentiate with respect to $\epsilon$.

I should expect to get a final value of 0 but I keep getting something like $m\epsilon \over 3$.

Am I not understanding the question will?

Comment: Why do you expect an answer of 0?  The answer should not have any terms in first order $\epsilon$.  I think you made a mistake in either taking the derivative of y or in integrating $L$.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/135330/2451