# What is meant by invariant under change of coordinates **to first order**?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, noethers-theorem

I am studying elementary Lagrangian mechanics, and I'm a bit confused about the what's meant by invariance of the Lagrangian under change of coordinates **to first order**.

More specifically, Noether's theorem states

> For each symmetry of the Lagrangian, there is a conserved quantity.

the textbook gives the following definition for symmetry:

> By 'symmetry', we mean that if the coordinates are changed by some small quantities, then the Lagrangian has no first-order change in these quantities.

Okay, but it does not mention what is meant by no change in first order. Does it mean all the terms are of first order?

For example, consider the Lagrangian $$L={m \over 2}({\dot x}^2+{\dot y}^2)-{k \over 2}(x^2+y^2)$$ and I let the change of coordinates be $$x \to x+ \epsilon y$$ $$y \to y-\epsilon x$$ and get $${dL \over d\epsilon} = \epsilon k(x^2+y^2)$$
so according to the textbook, a symmetry means no change of Lagrangian in first order of $\epsilon$, thus I should expect ${dL\over d\epsilon} =0$, so does this imply that I should evaluate the derivative at $\epsilon =0$, or is my interpretation problematic?

Comment: It's 'introduction to classical mechanics' by David Morin, and the definition is at page 236. This textbook is for freshman so I doubt its mathematical rigor.

Comment: First order in a Taylor expansion.

Comment: I know Taylor expansion, but does that mean, say if I have the term $x{\epsilon}^2$ and after differentiation with respect to $\epsilon$ I get $2x\epsilon$, so I need to set $\epsilon =0$ to show there is no change?

Comment: I will add a specific example to the question

Comment: $L(x+\varepsilon a) = L(x) + \mathcal{O}(\varepsilon^2)$. The form $x+\varepsilon a$ is achieved by linearising the actual symmetry operation.

Comment: I don't quiet understand the big O notation, does that mean all terms after ${\epsilon}^2$ are emitted?

Comment: If you like this Phys.SE question, you may also enjoy reading [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/135330/2451) Phys.SE post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The appropriate definition of symmetry uses infinitesimal quantities, not just *small quantities*. Thus, in terms of your question, the Lagrangian is symmetric if $dL/d\epsilon=0$ at $\epsilon=0$.

In terms of your example (rotation of a 2D harmonic oscillator), we have
$$
L \to (1+\epsilon^2) L = L + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)
$$
Thus to *first order* in $\epsilon$ $L$ does not change: it's invariant under rotations about the $z$-axis.

So, your interpretation appears correct.